# Logging skype in enterprise

Tags: logging, skype, sox

Are there tools or settings that can be used to log all conversations (text, voice if possible, file transmission) in enterprise environment? Folks want to use skype, but can't record same way as with e-mail.

Comment: Am I the only one that gets kind of chilled when the topic of recording everything your employees do comes up? Side note, the recording of everything is in your employee HR guidelines/policies, yes?

Comment: @Bart:  Many businesses have a need to record phone conversations.  I'm not reading this question as a way to spy on employees but rather to record conversations that occur through Skype on an as needed basis.

Comment: I know the requirement is there for certain businesses. It still is relevant to make sure that it's in the policies for employees. Many businesses/small businesses put in monitoring without telling their employees or don't think about the ramifications of doing it without telling them.

Comment: Plus...I simply get a little twinge when someone asks about something that boils down to monitoring someone. It sometimes feels clandestine or open to abuse. Maybe I've just seen it abused too often.

Comment: @Bart, Certain financial institutions need to preserve call records and communication to protect themselves in litigation. Rest assured, nobody is doing peeping Tom.

Answer (score 1):

Skype's encryption would make this very difficult (probably impossible) to do at the network level. Your options are to get spy software like Spector 360 or setup in internal communication tool that allows logging like Office Communications Server.

Comment: Installing software on PCs would be fine. Due to complex political issues, entire organization moved to Skype without considering impact. Now IT security are scratching their heads on what to do with it. Spector360 looks promising - no need to record all that detail, just some bits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Skype is set up as a tool meant to be easily monitored without tools set up on the end user PC (like parental control/monitoring software). The closest I can find is Skype Manager, which kind of sets up Skype within your business like a tool for VOIP communication and can give some statistics on usage. I don't think it'll tell you who's leaking company secrets, but it may tell you who's abusing the software to some degree. The PDF manual is located [here](http://download.skype.com/share/business/guides/skype-manager-user-guide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Setup up a skype gateway like asterix. You can do your call loging and monitoring on the gateway. More information here

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Skype+Gateways

Comment: That doesn't solve chats and skype2skype calls, does it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try building your internal application using the instructions at:
http://www.megapanzer.com/2009/08/04/watching-encrypted-skype-traffic-with-skypedllinjector/

Read more on that site about skype.